# Why am i getting the following error when trying the run Yarn start

Tags: sdk, unify, circuit-sdk

I'm getting the following error and i'm not sure where the problem is, can anyone help please?

```
            Server listening at port 3100
            Error
                at new circuit.Error (C:\Users\chrisconnolly\node_modules\circuit-sdk\circuit.js:311:22)
                at C:\Users\chrisconnolly\node_modules\circuit-sdk\circuit.js:54880:32
                at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5) {
              code: 'SDK_ERROR',
              message: 'The Application null  is not enabled for scope ::=[ALL]',
              stack: 'Error\n    at new circuit.Error ' +
                '(C:\\Users\\chrisconnolly\\node_modules\\circuit-sdk\\circuit.js:311:22)\n' +
                '    at ' +
                'C:\\Users\\chrisconnolly\\node_modules\\circuit-sdk\\circuit.js:54880:32\n' +
                '    at processTicksAndRejections ' +
                '(internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)'
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'ALL' scope is deprecated and instead individual scopes should be defined. The latest circuit-sdk will map 'ALL' to all individual scopes. So please update the circuit-sdk module via `yarn upgrade circuit-sdk` or `npm update circuit-sdk` and try again.

I also update the repo with the latest circuit-sdk and additionally specified the scopes in the config template.